# How to use the method 'include?' of the class Mongoid::Criteria?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongoid

The class document of [Mongoid::Criteria](http://rdoc.info/github/mongoid/mongoid/Mongoid/Criteria) doesn't mention anything about the method 'include?'. I think it should behave like Array.include?, but it isn't.

Here is an example showing that how an array works.,

```
months = ['January', 'February', 'March']
months.include? 'January' #=> true
months.include? 'Jan'     #=> false
```

For a collection model Month which has fields month(String), created_at, updated_at. However, `Month.where(month: /a/).include? 'January'` or `'Jan'` always returns false.

Is there a similar method doing the same as Array.include? for Mongoid?, and how to use this 'include?' method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Array.include?(element) works perfect in mongoid.

When you run User.all, it returns mongoid criteria. While the include works on array. Either user to_a or entries like Story.all.entries to change it to array.

```
User.all.to_a.include?(User.first)
```

will give true.

After your qsn update, i'll try to explain it.

```
Month.where(month: /a/)
```

This returns a mongoid criteria. Now

```
Month.where(month: /a/).include? or Month.where(month: /a/).entries.include?
```

expects an object to compare with and not string. It's like if this query returns few months as objects and now you execute

```
Month.where(month: /a/).include?(month_obj)
```

will give true if month_obj has month with text containing `"a"`. Hope this answer answers your query

Comment: Can you help with the updated question? It seems your answer doesn't work for my specific case?

Comment: @canoe check with my updated ans, it clearly answers your query

Comment: month_obj = Month.new month: 'January'; but the include? still returns false.

Comment: can you please write the complete query here, Month.new month: 'January'; will not save the data to db, it just instantiates the object with data

Comment: Yes, It's not saved into DB yet. But how to new a month_obj? My query is to create a month_obj just like in my previous comment, then Month.where(month: /a/).include?(month_obj) returns false.

Comment: you need to save the object

Comment: Now I understand how the include? method and Mongoid::Criteria work. They both require persistent data inputs. Thanks a lot.